# Chracter codes in sql 'like' queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been putting some data I have into my database. One of the files was somehow corrupted or something - it randomly has the character with value 6, `ACK`, in various unexpected places in place of real letters. This is causing me various problems with duplications in my database and so on - for instance, one company has two entries in my database, one as `Afh Engineering Ltd.`, the other as `Afh Engineerin Ltd.` (SO may clean that character - basically the 'g' is replaced with an `ACK` character.)

I want to do a query for all the companies in my database that have this problem. Something like:

```
select * from users where CompanyName like '%06%'
```

but obviously for the character with value '6' rather than the character representing the indo-arabic numeral '6'.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM users
    WHERE CHARINDEX(CHAR(6), CompanyName) <> 0
```